# How to exclude today ( upto 2.30PM ) data row from MYSQL fetch array

Tags: php, mysql

**In MySql...**

How to exclude today date ( upto 2.30PM on each day ) data row from MYSQL fetch array..
How to publish today result + last 3 using  PHP  + mysql ...

*Sample Table : ALLRESULTDATA*

```
id  price   date 
1   Rs.50   2015-12-09

2   Rs.5    2015-12-10

3   Rs.52   2015-12-11

4   Rs.55   2015-12-12  
5   Rs.53   2015-12-13  
6   Rs.53   2015-12-14
```

How to fetch last 3 days result ( Exclude today result upto 2.30PM afterthat publish TODAY)

```
mysql_query("select * from ALLRESULTDATA desc limit 4");
```

Comment: Can you clear with more details?

Comment: Is the date column a varchar or a DATETIME/TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Give the table definition so we can help

Comment: if those entries are the result of the query you gave us then its definitively not DATETIME nor TIMESTAMP

Comment: Tnks for all ... date is varchar(10) ...

Comment: Why downvoted friends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that will include the row for today and the rows for the last three days:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALLRESULTDATA
WHERE
  `date` = CURDATE()
  OR 
  `date` >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 4
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88561/3

I think you also mean to only include the result for today if the time is after 14:30, that's probably possible but it would be clunky in MySQL in my opinion.

I think you would be better grabbing the current time in php and if it's greater, running the query above and if not, run a different query, e.g. :

```
SELECT *
FROM ALLRESULTDATA
WHERE
  `date` != CURDATE()
  AND
  `date` >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

i.e. change the first conditional operator to `!=` and change the `OR` to an `AND` and then also change the `LIMIT` to `3`.

Today Excluded Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88561/5

**EDIT**

I just noticed your comment saying that the dates are stored as a `VARCHAR(10)`, if possible I'd recommend changing your schema so that the dates are stored as `DATE`.

An alternative is the [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, but I don't think the performance will be particularly nice if you have to resort to using it.

Comment: @UiDesigner don't forget to mark the answer as accepted with the Green Check Mark to the left of the answer